# sharepoint development environment

Tags: 2010, development, sharepoint-server, environment

Does Microsoft provide free online development environment for SharePoint 2010?

If yes . Please can you share the link and how to access it

Even if access is limited to one month or so...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the MSDN subscription then you will get the credit for windows Azure, where you can build a VM and configure SharePoint on it.

check this blog for more details: 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudiouk/archive/2013/08/08/making-the-most-of-your-free-azure-benefits-with-msdn.aspx

Another Option is Build VM on your PC and install trial version of SharePoint and do the development.

You can also check the SharePoint Hosting companies few give you some free trail but i dont think so you will get server access from them.

Comment: I need to test a webpart that interacts with SharePoint and AD.. Which paid providers do you suggest if at all?

Comment: I am not sure if any paid provider give you the AD access, In your case i would say build your own farm( VM) or use the windows azure with MSDN subscription.

Comment: can you suggest an article to get the VM ready. I am developer and do not have infrastructure knowledge.. I have got a 64bit PC. please guide.

Comment: here is one: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee554869(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: another one http://smallcitydesign.com/how-to-build-a-sharepoint-2010-development-machine/